# how to solve warning in android program "never read locally"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Why I am getting a warning saying:

```
The field testscreen.ScaleAnimToShow.mVanishAfter is never read locally testscreen.java /testscreen/src/com/testscreen  line 186    Java Problem
```

from the following code?

```
public class ScaleAnimToShow extends ScaleAnimation{
       private View mView;
       private LayoutParams mLayoutParams;
       private int mMarginBottomFromY, mMarginBottomToY;
       private boolean mVanishAfter = false;

       public ScaleAnimToShow(float toX, float fromX, float toY, float fromY, int duration, View view,boolean vanishAfter){
           super(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
           openLayout = view;
           setDuration(duration);
           mView = view;
           mVanishAfter = vanishAfter;
           mLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
           mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           int height = mView.getHeight();
           //mMarginBottomFromY = (int) (height * fromY) + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin + height;
           //mMarginBottomToY = (int) (0 - ((height * toY) + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin)) + height;
           mMarginBottomFromY = 0;
           mMarginBottomToY = height;
           Log.v("CZ",".................height..." + height + " , mMarginBottomFromY...." + mMarginBottomFromY  + " , mMarginBottomToY.." +mMarginBottomToY);
       }
```

Comment: Are you reading the value of `mVanishAfter` anywhere in that class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you have the field that occupies some space in memory but which is never read anywhere in your program.

You can resolve this warning:

- Remove this field. If you don't use it, don't keep it in your code.
  ***or***
- Add `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation. This may be useful when this field is used via annotation, or you want to keep it in code for other reasons.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private boolean mVanishAfter = false;
```

Comment: I have posted the complete class code above, please see. I tried removing _private boolean mVanishAfter = false;_ then I get lot of error messages. I know _@SuppressWarning("unused")_ will not display the warning but how to actually solve the problem so that I don't have to hide the warning ?

Comment: You should remove this field and a place where your write to this field: `mVanishAfter = vanishAfter;`. This will both resolve warning without introducing error.

Comment: Should I remove it from here also: _public ScaleAnimToShow(float toX, float fromX, float toY, float fromY, int duration, View view,**boolean vanishAfter**)_

Comment: You can, but that is not required.

Answer (score 2):

You have a private class member, mVanishAfter, that is never read.  Since it is private in the class, the IDE can see it is never used, which appears to be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Because you never read `mVanishAfter`. At least in the code you posted, you only ever assign to it, and because it is private it can never be read from anywhere else. A variable isn't "read" when it is assigned to.

Comment: I have posted the complete class code above, please see. I tried removing _private boolean mVanishAfter = false;_ then I get lot of error messages. I know _@SuppressWarning("unused")_ will not display the warning but how to actually solve the problem so that I don't have to hide the warning ?